# Duplicate class error on build for Jackson plugin

Tags: android, gradle, jackson

After opening a project I have been working on for a while that I haven't had open in a couple months, I am getting an error when trying to compile my Android Project. The error I get can be seen here: 
[image]

My project build gradle is as following:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And my app build.gradle dependencies are as following (few elements removed due to sensitive data):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.x.x"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 45
        versionName "1.45.1"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation files('libs/jackson-core-2.7.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jackson-databind-2.7.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.7.0.jar')
    // for joda
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.2'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner:htmlcleaner:2.16'
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:1.7.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    configurations.all {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
    }
}
```

I tried changing the

```
    implementation files('libs/jackson-core-2.7.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jackson-databind-2.7.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.7.0.jar')
```

To a newer version (2.9.9, after I downloaded them manually), but to no avail. The error just says the same as the image above, but with 2.9.9 instead of 2.8.7.

I also tried changing the `implementation files` to just an `implementation`, which utilizes Gradle to download the plugin, but it gave the same error.

I of course also tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, which also did nothing.

The full error from my Build Output window can be seen at https://pastebin.com/EPUuEXTd.

I have looked around at different answers both here on StackOverflow and on Github, but have found no questions that could be related to mine.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up fixing it by myself. The error occurred when I included the `implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:1.7.5'` dependency. I found out after some trial-and-error that this caused the error because `Sentry` includes their own version of the `Jackson` library, so I had both included it by myself and included it via `Sentry`.

Removing the

```
    implementation files('libs/jackson-core-2.7.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jackson-databind-2.7.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.7.0.jar')
```

Did however not fix the problem, because the files were still in the project. I needed to delete the 3 `.jar` files from the project folder entirely for the error to disappear. I then re-added jackson as dependency implementations, but this time via Gradle, and not via the file-system, so like this:

```
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.9'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.9'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9'
```

And now everything works. Mind you - the version numbers of `Sentry` and `Jackson` made no difference, I just decided to update while I was at it.